# How to apply different UI with same elements in same view controller (iOS)?

Tags: ios, user-interface, layout, constraints

I'm using Swift in Xcode 7 with Storyboard. I have different UI with same elements in same view controller. Depending on the data fetched from server, I wish to display different UI layout.

To make it easier to understand, e.g. I have one view controller with one label aligned the bottom of the view. While data is fetched from server, I want to display the label with different layout:

- If server returns `layout` as `bottom`, I'll apply the layout of text as `align bottom` and `centre horizontally`
- If server returns `layout` as `centre`, I want to apply the layout of text as `centre vertically` and `centre horizontally`

As a result, if I have many elements, it becomes hard for me to code the NSLayoutConstraint manually. Is there anyway I can still use Interface Builder to have different UI which applied to same view controller?

Comment: what are the many elements and how do they relate to each other?

Comment: The relation will be different significantly that is hard to track relation among elements. I want to have different UI according to the response from server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before and managed to come with a solution, though it is probably not how it was intended by apple. I tested and it works with xcode 6 and 7, possibly earlier versions too. Your question does not say if you are working with nibs or storyboards, but the answer I'm providing is for nibs. To set up your nib you need to add 2 view controllers or more.Set up your view controllers the way you need them to look and set the view controllers' main view's tag so you can differentiate them. To be able to connect your IBOutlets you will need to apply a bit of a trick:

- You set the first view controller's class so you can connect the
  outlets.
- You connect the outlets. You delete the class name in the
  attribute inspector. (Note that the outlets in the nib stay
  connected, but in the .m or .h file they show they are not. If you
  try to build your project now it will fail.)
- You set the second view controller's class so you can connect the outlets again.
- You connect the outlets again. You re-enter the class name in the attribute inspector for the first view controller.

Now you just need to get to your view controllers. For this I use a class method to get an instance of the view controller:

```
+ (UIViewController *)customViewControllerForLayout:(NSInteger)layoutTag
{
    NSArray *customViewControllers = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Your nib's name" owner:self options:nil];

    __block UIViewController *customViewControllerWithSpecifiedLayout = nil;
    [customViewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIViewController *customViewController, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (customViewController.view.tag == layoutTag) {
            customViewControllerWithSpecifiedLayout = customViewController;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    return customViewControllerWithSpecifiedLayout;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to give context. I'm using Swift in Xcode 7 with Storyboard.